# Bash - Using awk to parse values from CSV then return values via ldap-search

Tags: bash, csv, awk, ldap

Attempting to feed a CSV into a Bash shell script then parse it with awk to get usernames to feed into an ldapsearch. Then I would like to return values from ldapsearch indicating whether the user is active or inactive.

Everything works up until I get to awk part. I think my syntax is off here. Currently receiving: awk: illegal statement at source line 1.

```
echo Enter path to CVS:
read csv_File

input="$csv_File"
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
do
    awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," ; ldapsearch -Hldap://splunk.local -x -D "$admin@ldap.server" -w $ad_Password -b "CN=$8,OU=Standard,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=controller" -s sub "(cn=*)" cn useraccountcontrol'

done
```

-

Comment: Actually just caught the trailing bracket - but now the command seems to just hang with no output.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your latest update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is not shell. You can't just call some UNIX program like `ldapsearch` directly from an awk script - that's what shell is for, awk is for manipulating text files.

You don't need/want awk or a shell loop at all for this, all you need is:

```
cut -d, -f8 "$csv_File" |
xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -I {} ldapsearch -Hldap://splunk.local -x -D "$admin@ldap.server" -w "$ad_Password" -b "CN={},OU=Standard,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=controller" -s sub "(cn=*)" cn useraccountcontrol'
```

The above uses GNU xargs for `-d '\n'`.

Read [Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do) to learn awk, [Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594711) to learn shell, and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to learn more about loops in shell specifically.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. - The column of data had a space that needed to be accounted for. My end recipe looked like this:  `cut -d, -f8 "$csv_File" | sed 's/.*/"&"/' |`   `xargs -n 1 -I {} ldapsearch -Hldap://domain -x -D "$admin@domain" -w "$ad_Password" -b "CN={},OU=Contractors,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=controller" -s sub "(cn=*)" cn useraccountcontrol`

Comment: You definitely do NOT need to pipe cut to sed. Use `xargs -d '\n' ...` instead with GNU xargs. I updated the answer to show that. If that doesn't work lin your xargs let me know and we'll use an awk solution instead of cut+sed.

Comment: Getting `xargs: illegal option -- d`

Comment: As I said - "The above uses GNU xargs for -d '\n'." and "Use xargs -d '\n' ... instead with GNU xargs"? Get GNU xargs, I'm not interested in revisiting a week-old question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `while-read` loop for which you have given no input, so the shell is waiting for you to type some lines so `read` can read it.

What do you think you need awk for? You have already read the comma-separated fields into variables. You probably just need something like

```
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
do
    ldapsearch -Hldap://splunk.local -x -D "$admin@ldap.server" -w "$ad_Password" -b "CN=$f8,OU=Standard,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=controller" -s sub "(cn=*)" cn useraccountcontrol
    # ....................................................................................^^ you want $f8 here, I presume
done < "$csv_File"
# ...^^^^^^^^^^^^^ you need to give `read` something to read.
```